# spring oauth2 authorization code flow , configuration for VK (Vkontakte)

Tags: spring, vk, spring-oauth2

I'm using social network Vkontakte as Oauth2 authorization server. So I have several steps: 
1) get code with request with *request_type=code*
2) get accessToken when I send request to access token uri

[image]

So I want to use Spring Oauth2, but I should get authorization code first, then access token, i've tried to add to application.yml :

```
authorized-grant-types: authorization_code
```

it's my application.yml:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: [clientId]
      clientSecret: [clientSecret]
      accessTokenUri: https://oauth.vk.com/access_token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://oauth.vk.com/authorize
      tokenName: access_token
      registered-redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/login
    resource:
      token-info-uri: http://localhost:8080/user
```

but actually it doesn't help. If somebody faced it and know how to configure Spring Oauth2 app - will be grateful for help

Comment: Please post more details about your configurations, registered clients, sent requests and all relevant codes

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding what you mean by authoriztion_code, but the authorization_code is something you generate for your users without them authenticating themselves. For example, think about when you do a password reset. In that scenario you would generate an autorization code and email it to the user. The access token is what a user gets for successfully authenticating himself, either using username and password or an authorization code. This is a massive oversimplification, but hopefully clears things up a bit.

Comment: @Leon i've updated question, i use social network authorization server api to get code, then i have to get access token

Comment: i am totally fine with this tutorial i had to pay more attention to investigation: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually after couple days of investigation i figured out that Spring OAuth2 completely implementing all features and configuration to my client application uses the [authorization code grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4) to obtain an access token from Vkontakte (the Authorization Server)

[image]

The only thing i need to do if i take as sample [Spring Boot and OAuth2 social login simple](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_simple) is to populate *application.yml* with correct creds for my Authorization server:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: xxxxxxx
      clientSecret: xxxxxxxxxxx
      accessTokenUri: https://oauth.vk.com/access_token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://oauth.vk.com/authorize
      tokenName: code
      authenticationScheme: query
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
      grant-type: authorization_code
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://api.vk.com/method/users.get
```

The only problem i faced was providing correct *token name* and *userInfoUri* to retrieve logged user info.

According **token name** it is name of authorization code your get after passing authoriztion(response_type=**token name**, it calls **code** in my case) and use to get access token.

Hope it will be helpful people face the same problem